# How can I add a UIToolbar to my UITableViewController?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, interface-builder, uitableview, uitoolbar

I have a UITableViewController. I'd like to display a UIToolbar at the bottom but am not sure how I can do this as IB does not let me add it.

Comment: have you tried to add it progammatically as subview of your UITableViewController?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just try with it:

**In .h file:**

```
UIToolbar* toolbar;
```

**In .m file**

```
UIBarButtonItem *actionButton  = [[UIBarButtonItem  alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemAction target:self action:@selector(doAction)];
    toolbar           = [UIToolbar new];
    toolbar.barStyle  = UIBarStyleDefault;

    [toolbar sizeToFit];
    CGFloat toolbarHeight = [toolbar frame].size.height;
    CGRect mainViewBounds = appDel.window.bounds;
    [toolbar setFrame:CGRectMake(CGRectGetMinX(mainViewBounds),
                                 438,
                                 CGRectGetWidth(mainViewBounds),
                                 toolbarHeight)];       

    [[[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow] addSubview:toolbar];
```